# How to change checkbox icon (eg:pretty checkbox) in agGrid?

Tags: angular6, ag-grid

I'm using agGrid to render the data. There is a checkbox in the table to select the row in the table. I want to change the default icon tick style to pretty checkbox icon. How to change the icon style in agGrid, **without using cell renderer component**.